Synchronize reminders into multiple calendars
I an using a self-hosted CalDav server for sychronization of my most important events between PC and smartphone. As the definition is quite limited I'd like to use remind instead and synchronize all events to CalDav using rem2dav. This works in general, but with the limitation that neither Thunderbird nor the smartphone app allow customizing colors for individual events. So I came up with the idea to use multiple calendars instead.
Now I am exporting work events in one calendar, holidays in another etc. Unfortunately this does not allow for using OMIT and SKIP anymore if they are not exported to the same calendar. Therefore a weekly meeting will now be issued when I am on vacation, which is exactly what I wanted to avoid and why I wanted to use remind in the first place.
Is there a way to export only one reminder file, but still take another's definitions into account?

I managed to get the export to work by creating a custom export script. It basically does the following:

Read each reminder file and add a custom tag to all contained events (e.g. add TAG Work to all events in the file "work.rem")
Store all adapted events in a global variable
Remove messages from events not matching tag (e.g. OMIT 2000-01-01 TAG Holiday MSG New Year => OMIT 2000-01-01 TAG Holiday MSG for work calendar export)
Pipe all events to rem2dav so that OMIT events are available but do not create an actual calendar entry
Repeat with step 3 for next calendar/tag export

